# Spring mvc 3.1 not able to resolve URI templates

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a controller class configured with a URI template pattern. However when I redirect to this controller from another controller class it is not able to find this handler method.

I see an error in the logs which says "RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler  method for /path2/2" and then "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/path2/2] in DispatcherServlet.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/path1")
public class Controller1 {

  @RequestMapping (method = MethodRequest.POST)
  public String postMethod() {
      // some logic
      return "redirect:/path2/" + 2;
  }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/path2/${id}")
public class Controller2 {

  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView getMethod(@PathVariable("id") long id) {

    return new ModelAndView("some jsp");
  }
}
```

If I change the RequestMapping on Controller2 class to just "/path2/" and redirect to that url, the redirection works fine. Can someone please advise? 
I have DispatcherServlet configured in my web.xml and an InternalResourceViewResolver in my servlet context file.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is

```
@RequestMapping("/path2/{id}")
```

not

```
@RequestMapping("/path2/${id}")
```

Comment: Ahh!! Spent a few hours debugging this.  Thanks!!